# Copy single words of a sentence C

Tags: c

I made this little program that divides a word into single letters (like Hello: H-e-l-l-o).

```
int i;
  char str[50],str2[2];
  printf("insert something \n");
  scanf("%s", str);
  for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
   {
   strcpy (str2,str[i]);
   //printf("%c", str[i]);
  }
```

it works fine, but now I want that every word gets in a `char`
I tried to use the `strcpy (str2,str[i]);` but doesn't work :(

Comment: `char str2[2] = {0}; str2[0] = stri[i]: /* printf("%s ", str2); */`

Comment: @Simone don't ignore the warnings that your compiler gives you they are there for a reason.

Comment: @Simone  It is not clear what exactly you want.:)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks man it works!  Anyway thank you all for the answers!:)!

Answer (score 0):

In your case,

```
 strcpy (str2,str[i]);
```

the destination `str2` is not long enough to hold the *entire* source string. So, by running out of bondary, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For reference, `C11` standard, chapter §7.24.1

> [...] If an array is accessed beyond the end of an object, the behavior is undefined.

You can use array indexing instead to *extract* and print each element in the array.

Comment: Man the str2 will contain just 1 word, if the word is for example "Hello" the str2 will contain "H" then "e" and so on